# What type of database bitcore uses?

Tags: bitcore

Im looking at bitcore node ant insight projects (bitcore.io). Does the bitcore makes the copy of blockchain into the database? And what type of database they use? I just found that its needed 200gb of disk space. I need to put whole blockchain into my database, so im not sure if bitcore doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe bitcore uses an altered version of bitcoind and it stores data in a leveldb database. Bitcore will download the full blockchain.